# isEqualToString not returning true

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

The "Stopping" statement never gets printed even if you type 'stop' when running the program. Is the `initWithUTF8String:` method introducing extra formatting?

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    char holderText[256];

    fgets(holderText, 256, stdin);
    NSString *words = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:holderText];


    if ([words isEqualToString:@"stop"]) {

        NSLog(@"STOPPING");

    }
    NSLog(@"This is what you typed: %@", words);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: NSLog is outside the if so it gets printed anyway. It displays the text i entered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine, even though you're leaking the `words` string. You need to add an `[autorelease]` on the end of that alloc call.

You could try `initWithCString` and also trim new lines and surrounding whitespace.

```
NSString *words = [[[NSString alloc] initWithCString:holderText] autorelease];
words = [words stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Using Garbage Collection so wouldn't need autorelease. But thanks.

Comment: Ahh. Well I suppose that'll apply to iOS :P

Answer (score 6):

`fgets` will include the trailing newline in the string it gives you (except in the case where it wouldn't fit in the buffer but that's not so here), so it will be `"stop\n"` rather than `"stop"`.

Changing the log line to:

```
NSLog(@"This is what you typed: [%@]", words);
```

should hopefully make it clear what's happening.

Either modify the comparison to take this into account, or trim the newline off before comparing.

Comment: ah! so I have to manually remove \n at the end or use scanf? Is there a better way to get input from stdin and put it in a NSString?

Comment: `scanf` (at least the unbounded `"%s"` variant) is always a bad idea for user input (the `f` is for formatted and there's precious _less_ formatted than user input). You can either trim or just change the comparison to include a newline - the latter is probably the fastest/easiest though some purists will insist it looks ugly :-)

Answer (score 3):

Since `fgets` will probably include a trailing newline, you might want to do a trim of all newlines in the string by using `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`:

```
NSString *trimmed = [words stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

if([trimmed isEqualToString:@"stop"]]) {
  //...
}
```