# Comparing strings to keyboard input in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm having some trouble comparing NSStrings in Objective C. I looked at apples documentation, and it appears that there is a function that returns a boolean called isEqualToString. However, the statement never executes.

```
NSString* randomCombo = @"rypo";

NSFileHandle* kbd = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData* inputData = [kbd availableData];
NSString* line = [[NSString alloc]initWithData : inputData encoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"You entered: %@", line);
NSLog(@"The string to match is: %@", randomCombo);

if([line isEqualToString : randomCombo]){
    NSLog(@"you win.");
}
```

Do I need to encode the NSString, randomCombo? Can anybody help me figure out what the problem is here?

Comment: Are you sure line is equal to randomCombo in the output?

Comment: Mmmm.  Change your `NSLog` statements temporarily for debugging purposes.  Try `NSLog(@"You entered: [%@]",line);` and `NSLog(@"The string to match is: [%@]",randomCombo);`  This will wrap the strings in brackets to be as sure as possible that the values are actual identical, even whitespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [isEqualToString not returning true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025663/isequaltostring-not-returning-true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use <kbd>return</kbd> to end your input, there's a newline character appended to the string which the other string doesn't have.

You need to either terminate input using <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, which just closes the pipe without starting a new line, or trim the `'\n'` off of the string afterwards.